# SMTP return different value message

Tags: go, formatting, smtp

My purpose is to send filtered values using SMTP Gmail. But I got different values from the message. Here I got character count from the message that I need.

```
func main() {
    links := []string{"http://grafana.url.io/api/datasources/proxy/2/query?db=telegraf&q=SELECT%20last(%22used_percent%22)%20AS%20used%20FROM%20%22disk%22%20WHERE%20(%22path%22%20%3D%20'%2F')%20AND%20time%20%3E%3D%20now()%20-%2030s%20GROUP%20BY%20time(10s)%2C%20host%20ORDER%20BY%20desc&epoch=ms"}

    fmt.Println("CPU with the condition over than 80%: ")
    
    if err := checkURLS(links); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err:", err)
        return
    }
    checklink, _ := fmt.Println(links)

    subject := "TESTING SOME subject"
    message := []byte("Subject:" + subject + "\n\n" +
        "CPU with the condition over than 80%: \n" +
        fmt.Sprint(checklink))
    fmt.Println(string(message))
    fmt.Println("Email Sent!")
}
```

Result:

```
Subject: TESTING SOME subject

CPU with the condition over than 25%: 
28
```

Expected:

```
Subject: TESTING SOME subject

CPU with the condition over than 25%: 
[{"ha-external-01":45.804}]
```

any suggestion? My plain full code on this https://play.golang.org/p/_fwy38hQwVv

Answer (score 0):

To cite [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail):

> The `msg` parameter should be an RFC 822-style email with headers first, a blank line, and then the message body. The lines of `msg` should be CRLF terminated. The `msg` headers should usually include fields such as "From", "To", "Subject", and "Cc". Sending "Bcc" messages is accomplished by including an email address in the to parameter but not including it in the `msg` headers.
>
> The `SendMail` function and the `net/smtp` package are low-level mechanisms and provide no support for DKIM signing, MIME attachments (see the `mime/multipart` package), or other mail functionality. Higher-level packages exist outside of the standard library.

This part itself already mentions CRLF (`\r\n`) used for line termination in the messages transmitted using SMTP (and you're using sole LFs).

You could read [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) (or more up-to-date versions of this original spec) to learn more on how SMTP messages are formatted, but I admit it's hard to grok.

Still, if your messages are guaranteed to be all-ASCII and have sensible line lengths, you could get away with just using proper line termination. Otherwise I'd look at [`github.com/go-gomail/gomail`](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail): you can copy its approach to formatting SMTP messages or use its `Message` type which is able to properly serialize itself to any `io.Writer` (which can be a `*bytes.Buffer`, for example).